# can we pay the gas price in form of token?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

can we pay the gas price in form of ERC20 token without using the ether? if ERC20 token has a value.then can we pay the gas price in form of ERC20 token.

Answer (score 4):

As per ethereum blockchain consensus algorithm, ETH(ether) is fuel for ethereum blockchain and miners paid by only ether(ETH) for any transaction occurs in the network whether it is failed or success.

> And **Each token is it’s own mini-database of who owns what**. The
>   “token” is just an entry in the token contract, and who “owns” a token
>   is recorded in the contract. A token is never in “your” wallet. So you can not pay gas fees using token.

First you have to understand what is token in deep and for your question refer this [article.](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/gas/what-is-gas-ethereum.html)

Comment: for transfering the token from one address to another address. can we pay the gas price in form of ERC20 token?

Comment: As you have in the answer above, no. It is a transaction.

Comment: I think you have not read the article that I shared in the last of my answer. I recommend you to read that article first. you will clear doubts from there.

Comment: can we make contract owner has to pay the Gas Price for other user?

Comment: I didn't get this @Nithin,  post this comment as a new question with more details.